# Get $state url in $http interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to hanlde my 404 errors properly in my Angular app.
The redirection works fine here but somehow I cannot manage to get the $state url here. The `window.location.href` gets printed jsut fine bu I get nothing for `$injector.get('$state').current.url`.

```
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push([
    '$q',
    '$rootScope',
    '$injector',
    function($q, $rootScope, $injector) {
      return {
       'request': function(config) {
           return config;
        },
        'responseError': function(response) {
          console.log(window.location.href);
          console.log($injector.get('$state').current.url);
          //404 error handling
          if (response.status === 404)
            $injector.get('$state').go('404')

          //500 error handling
          if (response.status === 500)
            $injector.get('$state').go('500')

          return response;
        }
      };
    }]);
  }])
```

I cannot figure out where the problem comes from. Does anyone has an idea?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

What are you really trying to catch as an error : ?

- a route change which failed (due to a failed ui-router resolve) ?
- any http request ? (which is not linked to ui-router)

If it's a routeChange error, you should take a look at the ui-router `$stateChangeError` event which will get fired when any resolve fails

Example :

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, to, toParams, from, fromParams, reason) {
    // error handling code
    // you can use params to retrieve from/to route
});
```

If you want to catch any http request like your code snippet, you're code can work only if ui-router had the time to iniatialized itself .. and you can't be sure of that if you don't use ui-router events.